# how to develope two layer of images and both the layers should have some motion activity in android

Tags: android

i want to have a background image and it should have some motion. then in the foreground another image which should also have some other motion.i.e two layer of images each having separate motion event

Answer (score 0):

You can stack two views on top of each other with a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout and apply animations to each one of them with startAnimation().

Comment: yes i did all that but i dont know how to apply animation with start animation. can u help me

Comment: maybe you can post an excerpt of your code since I cannot tell what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bitmap or Drawable to draw your image. So you will have something like this -

Assuming you have image1 and image2 in res/drawable folders and you know how to load them in your program.

```
Drawable backgroundImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
Drawable foregroundImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image2);

backgroundImage.setBounds(x1, y1, x1 + width, y1 + height);
foregroundImage.setBounds(x2, y2, x2 + width, y2 + height);

// You need to declare Canvas in your code to use Drawable
backgroundImage.draw(canvas);
foregroundImage.draw(canvas);
```

Now through your code, control (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) to have separate motion for the two images. Hope that helps

Comment: sorry am new to android i dont know wat all to add in the above code. can you help me out

Comment: In that case I would suggest go through the following guide..http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

PLace the two image views in a frame layout initially and then apply the animation scheme to them.
Start the animation for  both the views and they will move.
For applying animation  you can create an animation xml in the "anim" in the "res" folder.
Info regarding this can be collected from 
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html